# Log in to new site when registered online is broken

Tags: bug, android-app

I've got version 1.0.24 of the android app.

On my computer (the one I'm posting from now, as a matter of fact) I

- signed up for the Chemistry SE and posted a question.
- I got an answer, which notified my phone app.
- After viewing the answer on my phone I decided I wanted to post a comment
- When I clicked "Add Comment" it popped up "Add to your sites?" dialog asking if I'd like to join.
- When I click "Join Site" I get a dropdown notification, "You're already a member of Chemistry."
- Cancel simply closes the dialog.
- I tried using the back button to exit out of the app and came back in - with exactly the same behavior.

I'm about to try flushing my stored data for the app.

## Edit:

Flushing my stored data worked.

Comment: If possible, write your edit as the answer (and explain it a bit more) since it worked for you. Though, maybe you better update the app to 1.0.28 :)

Comment: Great, now I want to update the app, join another site and post a question, just to see if the bug still exists ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Workaround

- I went to the phone settings > applications > installed/downloaded > Stack Exchange app
- clicked the "clear data" button
- opened the app again
- \o/ Sweet, sweet success.